# STM32F767ZI dual ADC mode triggered by timer

Tags: c, stm32f7

I'am working on a current controller to control the current in two coils simultaneously.
Therefor I want to measure two analog pins simultaneously and synchronised w.r.t. the PWM timer.

For PWM, I use timer TIM2. PWM is running properly.
Additionally, I configured ADC for dual injected simultaneous mode.

Now my question:
When I start the ADC by setting the JSWSTART-Bit of register ADC1_CR1 within the timer IRQ-Handler, the measurement is performed (software triggered ADC execution). But when I want to use the timer update event as ADC trigger, no measurement will be performed. What I'am doing wrong?

I use only low level functions of HAL library.

This is my code when using software triggered ADC.

```
void adcInit(){
    /* prepare ADC for synchronous measurement */
    LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    LL_ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStruct;
    LL_ADC_InitTypeDef ADC_InitStruct;
    LL_ADC_INJ_InitTypeDef ADC_INJ_InitStruct;

    /* enable clocks */
    LL_AHB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_AHB1_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOC);
    LL_APB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB2_GRP1_PERIPH_ADC1);
    LL_APB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB2_GRP1_PERIPH_ADC2);

    /* configure input channels */
    /* common to all pins */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
    /* internal current sensor coil C1 */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = ANALOG_CS_INT_C1_PIN;
    LL_GPIO_Init(ANALOG_CS_INT_C1_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    /* internal current sensor coil C2 */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = ANALOG_CS_INT_C2_PIN;
    LL_GPIO_Init(ANALOG_CS_INT_C2_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    /* external current sensor coil C1 */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = ANALOG_CS_EXT_C1_PIN;
    LL_GPIO_Init(ANALOG_CS_EXT_C1_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    /* external current sensor coil C2 */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = ANALOG_CS_EXT_C2_PIN;
    LL_GPIO_Init(ANALOG_CS_EXT_C2_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* initialize ADC register */
    /* use ADC1 & ADC2 in dual combined injected mode */
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.Multimode = LL_ADC_MULTI_DUAL_INJ_SIMULT;
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.CommonClock = LL_ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;     // 27MHz
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.MultiTwoSamplingDelay = LL_ADC_MULTI_TWOSMP_DELAY_5CYCLES;
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.MultiDMATransfer = LL_ADC_MULTI_REG_DMA_EACH_ADC;
    LL_ADC_CommonInit(ADC123_COMMON, &ADC_CommonInitStruct);

    ADC_InitStruct.Resolution = LL_ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
    ADC_InitStruct.DataAlignment = LL_ADC_DATA_ALIGN_RIGHT;
    ADC_InitStruct.SequencersScanMode = LL_ADC_SEQ_SCAN_DISABLE;
    LL_ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStruct);
    LL_ADC_Init(ADC2, &ADC_InitStruct);

    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.SequencerLength = LL_ADC_INJ_SEQ_SCAN_DISABLE;
    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.SequencerDiscont = LL_ADC_INJ_SEQ_DISCONT_DISABLE;
    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.TrigAuto = LL_ADC_INJ_TRIG_INDEPENDENT;
    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.TriggerSource = LL_ADC_INJ_TRIG_SOFTWARE;
    LL_ADC_INJ_Init(ADC1, &ADC_INJ_InitStruct);
    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.TriggerSource = LL_ADC_INJ_TRIG_SOFTWARE;    // disable trigger of ADC2, triggered by ADC1
    LL_ADC_INJ_Init(ADC2, &ADC_INJ_InitStruct);

    /* select channels and set sampling time*/
    LL_ADC_INJ_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_INJ_RANK_1, ANALOG_CS_C1_ADC_CH);
    LL_ADC_INJ_SetSequencerRanks(ADC2, LL_ADC_INJ_RANK_1, ANALOG_CS_C2_ADC_CH);

    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, ANALOG_CS_C1_ADC_CH, LL_ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_3CYCLES);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC2, ANALOG_CS_C2_ADC_CH, LL_ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_3CYCLES);

    /* enable interrupts */
    NVIC_SetPriority(ADC_IRQn, NVIC_PRIORITY_ADC);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
    LL_ADC_EnableIT_JEOS(ADC1);
    // JEOC-interrupt for ADC1 is sufficient, because interrupt is generated when injected channels have all been converted (manual p. 458)
    // LL_ADC_EnableIT_JEOS(ADC2);

    /* enable ADCs */
    LL_ADC_Enable(ADC1);
    LL_ADC_Enable(ADC2);
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void){
    static uint32_t ctrlExecCnt = PWM_TIMER_FREQ/CTRL_EXEC_FREQ;
    if(timer2.timer->SR & TIM_SR_UIF_Msk){
        timer2.timer->SR = ~(TIM_SR_UIF_Msk);
        if(!(timer2.timer->CR1 & TIM_CR1_DIR_Msk)){
            // reached counter bottom value, now counting up
            // update TIMx_CCRy value -> because of enabled preload, value will be applied when reaching timer top update event
            LL_TIM_OC_SetCompareCH3(timer2.timer, ctrlState.outC1);
            LL_TIM_OC_SetCompareCH4(timer2.timer, ctrlState.outC2);
            if(!--ctrlExecCnt){
                ctrlExecCnt = PWM_TIMER_FREQ/CTRL_EXEC_FREQ;
                execControlLoop();
            }
            LL_ADC_INJ_StartConversionSWStart(ADC1);
        }else{
            // reaching counter top value -> OC pin is low, so now direction could be changed
            if(ctrlState.dirC1 == POSITIVE){
                LL_GPIO_ResetOutputPin(DIR_C1_PORT, DIR_C1_PIN);
            }else{
                LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin(DIR_C1_PORT, DIR_C1_PIN);
            }
            if(ctrlState.dirC2 == POSITIVE){
                LL_GPIO_ResetOutputPin(DIR_C2_PORT, DIR_C2_PIN);
            }else{
                LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin(DIR_C2_PORT, DIR_C2_PIN);
            }
        }
    }
}

void ADC_IRQHandler(void){
    LL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin);
    // get interrupt source
    // checking ADC1 JEOC-interrupt is sufficient, because interrupt will be generated when all injected channels have been converted (manual p. 458)
    if(ADC1->SR & ADC_SR_JEOC_Msk){
        // both ADC1 & ADC2 injected conversion finished
        LL_ADC_ClearFlag_JEOS(ADC1);
        //LL_ADC_ClearFlag_JEOS(ADC2);
        // read in data
        adcData[0] = ADC1->JDR1;
        adcData[1] = ADC2->JDR1;
        char tmp[20];
        STM32_usartPrintf(&usart3, "ADC: ");
        utoa(adcData[0],tmp,10);
        STM32_usartPrintf(&usart3, tmp);
        STM32_usartPrintf(&usart3, "\t");
        utoa(adcData[1],tmp,10);
        STM32_usartPrintf(&usart3, tmp);
        STM32_usartPrintf(&usart3, "\r");
    }
}
```

Changes to use timer trigger:
Selected update event as trigger output for timer TIM2, and select TIM2_TRGO as ADC trigger source.
And I also commented the function setting the JSWSTART-Bit within the timer IRQ-Handler to not start ADC2 accidentally.

```
void adcInit(){
    ...
    LL_TIM_SetTriggerOutput(TIM2, LL_TIM_TRGO_UPDATE);
    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.TriggerSource = LL_ADC_INJ_TRIG_EXT_TIM2_TRGO;
    LL_ADC_INJ_Init(ADC1, &ADC_INJ_InitStruct);
    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.TriggerSource = LL_ADC_INJ_TRIG_SOFTWARE;    // disable trigger of ADC2, triggered by ADC1
    LL_ADC_INJ_Init(ADC2, &ADC_INJ_InitStruct);
    ...
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void){
    ...
//          LL_ADC_INJ_StartConversionSWStart(ADC1);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is quiet easy but not so easy to find :D

When using the low level HAL function `LL_ADC_INJ_Init(...)`, then the JEXTEN-bits in control register CR2 are cleared. And cleard JEXTEN-bits mean "no trigger evaluation". Additionally, the value assigned to `ADC_INJ_InitStruct.TriggerSource = LL_ADC_INJ_TRIG_EXT_TIM2_TRGO;` is masked so it isn't possible to set trigger source and trigger detection using the init function.
Doing it by myself, soves the problem. So the "solution" is

```
void adcInit(){
    ...
    LL_TIM_SetTriggerOutput(TIM2, LL_TIM_TRGO_UPDATE);
    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.TriggerSource = LL_ADC_INJ_TRIG_EXT_TIM2_TRGO;
    LL_ADC_INJ_Init(ADC1, &ADC_INJ_InitStruct);
    ADC1->CR2 |= (0x01 << ADC_CR2_JEXTEN_Pos);
    ADC_INJ_InitStruct.TriggerSource = LL_ADC_INJ_TRIG_SOFTWARE;    // disable trigger of ADC2, triggered by ADC1
    LL_ADC_INJ_Init(ADC2, &ADC_INJ_InitStruct);
    ...
}
```

The same behaviour should occure when using regular channels, because `ADC_REG_Init(...)` also clears EXTEN-bits. So in this case add
`ADC1->CR2 |= (0x01 << ADC_CR2_EXTEN_Pos);`